# Click show content and Hover updates content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row of button which will display the related content when it's clicked or hovered. But now I want the content to be updated temporarily when an other button is hovered while one is allready clicked.

So the problem is when I hover over the other button while one is allready clicked, it will show the content of it. But when my mouse leaves **it won't return back to the content from the button thats currently clicked.**

See my code:

```
 <div id="showcaseBttns">
  <a class="bttns" target="1">work 1</a>
  <a class="bttns" target="2">work 2</a>
  <a class="bttns" target="3">work 3</a>
</div>

<div id="main_left">
  <div id="work_main1" class="targetDiv">work 1</div>
  <div id="work_main2" class="targetDiv">work 2</div>
  <div id="work_main3" class="targetDiv">work 3</div>
</div>


var clicked = false;

$('[id ^= "work"]').hide();

$('.bttns').click(function() {

  clicked = !clicked;
  $('.targetDiv').hide();
  $('#work_main' + jQuery(this).attr('target')).show();

});

$('.bttns').hover(
  function() {
    $('#work_main' + jQuery(this).attr('target')).show()
  },
  function() {
    if (!clicked) {
      $('#work_main' + jQuery(this).attr('target')).hide()
    } else {
      $('#work_main' + jQuery(this).attr('target')).show()
    }
  });
```

see my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fp62L9g/

Comment: so you want always 1 result, the last hovered or clicked?

Comment: if button 1 is clicked it needs to show the content of it and when you hover button 2 it needs to show the content of button 2 until you exit the hover state. otherwise just display the content from the clicked button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
var $clicked;

 $('[id ^= "work"]').hide();

 $('.bttns').click(function() {
    var $newClicked = $(this),
      newClicked = $newClicked.attr('target'),
      oldClicked = $clicked && $clicked.attr('target');
      
    if (oldClicked && oldClicked === newClicked) {
      $('#work_main' + newClicked).hide();    
      $clicked = undefined;
      return;
    } 
    
   $clicked = $newClicked;
   $('.targetDiv').hide();
   $('#work_main' + newClicked).show();

 });

 $('.bttns').hover(
   function() {
      var hovTarget = $(this).attr('target');
     $('#work_main' + hovTarget).show();
      if ($clicked && $clicked.attr('target') !== hovTarget) {
        $('#work_main' + $clicked.attr('target')).hide();
      }
   },
   function() {
       $('.targetDiv').hide();
       $clicked && $('#work_main' +$clicked.attr('target')).show();
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcaseBttns">
  <a class="bttns" target="1">work 1</a>
  <a class="bttns" target="2">work 2</a>
  <a class="bttns" target="3">work 3</a>
</div>

<div id="main_left">
  <div id="work_main1" class="targetDiv">work 1</div>
  <div id="work_main2" class="targetDiv">work 2</div>
  <div id="work_main3" class="targetDiv">work 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes almost! but it's like div work_main1 is over ruling the other divs when its in clicked state. because when I hover on the other divs it wont show. how can I make the divs that can be hovered to overrule.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. So, when div1 is clicked and div2 is hovered - only div2's content should appear?

Comment: Indeed. And when unhovered, the content of the div which is clicked will re-appear.

Comment: See now, I have changed the snippet accordingly.

Comment: perfect my friend! just what i needed. one last thing: how can i make it if i click it again it will hide the div thats been clicked. or is it better to use Toggle if I want to achieve that?

Comment: Just toggling won't cut it. I have updated code. check

Comment: you the man! you got it what im looking for. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
var clickedId = null;

$('[id ^= "work"]').hide();

$('.bttns').click(function() {

  clickedId = jQuery(this).attr('target');
  $('.targetDiv').hide();
  $('#work_main' + jQuery(this).attr('target')).show();

});

$('.bttns').hover(
  function() {
    $('#work_main' + jQuery(this).attr('target')).show()
  },
  function() {
      $('#work_main' + jQuery(this).attr('target')).hide()
    if(clickedId!==null) {
      $('#work_main' + clickedId).show()
    }
  });
```

Comment: not working. it leaves the other divs out when button is clicked